# Nim for loop index cannot evaluate at compile time

Tags: nim-lang

Why does the following code throw `Error: cannot evaluate at compile time: i` when trying to compile:

```
import std/strutils

const s = "a"

for i in 1..10:
    const ss = s.repeat(i)
    echo ss
```

I tried without the loop

```
import std/strutils

const s = "a"
const ss = s.repeat(10)
echo ss
```

and it works as expected.

Comment: I'm still a bit new to Nim, so take what I say with a grain of salt, but it seems to me that you are reassigning `ss` in the for loop despite the fact that you can't reassign `const` expressions as that will give you a compile time error specifically because `const` variables are interpreted at compile time. 

Try replacing `const ss` in the for loop with the mutable expression `var ss`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that for loops store their iteration variable as a var or let depending on the iterator. So even if the range you give is static the iterator variable won't be. You can get around this by putting the entire loop in a `static:` block or a `{.compileTime.}` proc, or of course if you just want an immutable `ss` then you can use `let` instead of `const`.